# How to change the index of QStackedWidget from a contained widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, widget

I have a `QStackedWidget` that contains 2 layers of widgets (widget inside another widget).
The final widget contains a multiplicity of buttons. How can I change the index of that `QStackedWidget` when I press one of those buttons?

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question correct, the answer is simple -- have you tried:

```cpp
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(INDEX);
```

Comment: Sorry sir that's not what i mean because the widget inside is created as a separated widget so it does have other .h .cpp and .ui files that's my problem